# Inputlistener stays between classes

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

I am building a simple game with LIBGDX, and I have come across this irritating problem.

I have a MenuScreen.java class, which looks like this:

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Gqj1XDDM)'s the full class on pastebin

The important part is the imageButton's inputListener:

```
button.addListener(new InputListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    return true;
   }
   @Override
   public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    MineFinder.Log.debug("xpos: " + x + ", ypos: " + y);
    game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
   }
  });
```

My problem is, that if this class is present (and GameScreen gets called from this) for some reason if I click to the ImageButton's position in GameScreen, it still handles the input. This is really irritating, because if a player clicks on that part of the screen the game gets reseted.

If i remove references to my MenuScreen.java file, and skip it alltogether the problem isn't present, so I am pretty sure that the problem is that the InputListener doesn't get "deleted"

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `resize` method.  This line:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

sets the *global* input processor to be the stage.  The input handling code doesn't really care about what is being rendered on the screen.

I think the easiest fix is to set the input processor in `show` and clear it in `hide`.  Something like this:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
}
```

Alternatively, you could have your callbacks check to see if the button/stage/screen they are in is active, or unregister/re-register the callbacks in `show`/`hide`, depending on how you are using your Screens.